# mongoosse : How could I get a sum up total price

Tags: mongoose

I got a user schema ,and every user have their bought records.
Now , i need to get every user's total cost ,how can I get them ?

**userSchema :**

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const userInfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     userName: {
          type: String,
          required: [true, "A user must have a name"],
        },
    historyList:[
{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "History" }
    ]
    })

    const UserInfo = mongoose.model("UserInfo", userInfoSchema);
    
    module.exports = UserInfo;
```

**History Schema** :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const historySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  source: {
    type: Number,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
  },
  time: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});

const History = mongoose.model("History", historySchema);
module.exports = History;
```

** I would like to get a user's total cost ,and I got stuck here ...**

```
exports.getMyCost = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    const user = await UserInfo.findById(req.body._id);
    let total = 0 ;
   for(let i = 0 ;i<user.historyList.length;i++){
total + = user.historyList.price ; // here comes out with undefine...
}

    res.status(200).json({
      code: 200,
      total: 
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return next(
      res.status(400).json({
        code: 400,
        msg: error.message,
      })
    );
  }

}
```

Anyone can help ? Thank you so much in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `historyList` as a reference array, you must populate first, then iterate the array specifying the index.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population

```
const user = await UserInfo.findById(req.body._id).populate("historyList");
let total = 0 ;
for(let i = 0 ;i<user.historyList.length;i++){
   total + = user.historyList[i].price ; 
}
```

Even though, I would not recommend to do it like this. I suggest to do the reference the other way arround UserInfo->History and use aggregations. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate

```
const historySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userRef:{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "UserInfo" }
  ...
});
```